# WCF attributes and linq to sql

Tags: c#, wcf, linq-to-sql, sqlmetal

How can I generate `dbml` file (with `Sqlmetal.exe`) with appropiate WCF attributes (`DataMember`, `DataContract` etc)?

for example:
I have `Client` table with columns: `ClientID`, `Name`, `IP`, `City`, `Phone`

I'd like make `Client` class generated in dbml as `[DataContract]` and `Name` and `IP` as `[DataMember]`

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think this post in msdn blog[Enabling .dbml file for WCF](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2007/11/27/linq-to-sql-enabling-dbml-file-for-wcf.aspx) can be usefull