# How to force set EntityRef?

Tags: c#, linq, wcf

In my project I've two Interesting database tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User]
(
  [Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY, 
  [Name] NCHAR(60) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Event]
(
  [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY identity,
  ...  
  [User id] INT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [FK_Event_User] FOREIGN KEY ([User id]) REFERENCES [User](Id)
)
```

I want to have access to the Event's users in my Application which take data from WCF.

To make this possible I've to change `Child Property` in `User_Event Association` according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7970280/1565454) answer.

I use LINQ SQL and I noticed that `event.User` property is not null only when I invoke get properties on it.

Now I have to add for loop to force invoking `this._User.Entity`, but it don't look like this solution...

```
    public List<Event> GetAllEvents()
    {
        var ev = Database.Instance.Db.Events;
        foreach (var v in ev)
        {
            User u = v.User;
        }
        return ev.ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the problem was caused by `DataContext.DeferredLoadingEnabled` Property.

According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.deferredloadingenabled.aspx):

> DeferredLoadingEnabled
>
> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether to delay-load one-to-many or one-to-one relationships.

**update**

finally I've solved this problem with [LoadWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548760%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function from `Linq to SQL`.

```
db = new ModelDataContext();

/* setting lazy evaluation rules */
DataLoadOptions dlo = new DataLoadOptions();
dlo.LoadWith((Session s) => s.Exam);
dlo.LoadWith((Session s) => s.SessionUsers);
db.LoadOptions = dlo;
```